# Name an external dependency in Zipkin to have it drawn

Tags: zipkin, spring-cloud-sleuth

I am using Zipkin with Spring Sleuth to display traces. When I use it locally, http://localhost:9411/zipkin/dependency/ displays a nicely created graph of dependencies within the eco-system. Sometimes, backends from outside that eco-system get called and those are not displayed in that graph. Is it possible to annotate a call (let's assume RestTemplate and Feign clients) to such an external system so Zipkin would actually draw that dependency? If it's possible, what do I have to do?

This would be my baseline of code:

```
@Bean
RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate();
}

@RequestMapping("/")
public String callExternalBackend() {
    return restTemplate.getForObject("https://httpbin.org/get", String.class);
}
```

Somewhere I would like to type `httpbin` so this call gets drawn in the dependency-graph of Zipkin.

Thank you!

---

// **Edit** based on current solution
I'm using Spring Cloud Finchley and added the following line before restTemplate's call:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String callBackend() {
    spanCustomizer.tag("peer.service", "httpbin");
    return restTemplate.getForObject("https://httpbin.org/get", String.class);
}
```

I simply inject `SpanCustomizer` in this class. The Span is sent to Zipkin and I see the tag is set:

[image]

Unfortunately, it is not drawn in the dependencies-view. Is there anything else I need to configure, maybe in Zipkin rather than in Sleuth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDGWARE**

Have you read the documentation? If you use Spring Cloud Sleuth in Edgware version if you read the Sleuth section you would find this piece of the documentation https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Edgware.SR3/single/spring-cloud.html#_custom_sa_tag_in_zipkin

Let me copy that for you

> 54.5 Custom SA tag in Zipkin Sometimes you want to create a manual Span that will wrap a call to an external service which is not
>   instrumented. What you can do is to create a span with the
>   peer.service tag that will contain a value of the service that you
>   want to call. Below you can see an example of a call to Redis that is
>   wrapped in such a span.

```
org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.Span newSpan = tracer.createSpan("redis");
try {
    newSpan.tag("redis.op", "get");
    newSpan.tag("lc", "redis");
    newSpan.logEvent(org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.Span.CLIENT_SEND);
    // call redis service e.g
    // return (SomeObj) redisTemplate.opsForHash().get("MYHASH", someObjKey);
} finally {
    newSpan.tag("peer.service", "redisService");
    newSpan.tag("peer.ipv4", "1.2.3.4");
    newSpan.tag("peer.port", "1234");
    newSpan.logEvent(org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.Span.CLIENT_RECV);
    tracer.close(newSpan);
}
```

> [Important]   Important Remember not to add both peer.service tag and
>   the SA tag! You have to add only peer.service.

**FINCHLEY**

The `SA` tag will not work for Finchley. You have to do it in the following manner using the `remoteEndpoint` on the span.

```
    Span span = tracer.newTrace().name("redis"); 
    span.remoteEndpoint(Endpoint.newBuilder().serviceName("redis").build()); 
    span.kind(CLIENT);
    try(SpanInScope ws = tracer.withSpanInScope(span.start())) {
          // add any tags / annotations on the span
          // return (SomeObj) redisTemplate.opsForHash().get("MYHASH", someObjKey);
    } finally {
      span.finish();
    }
```

Comment: Oh, there it is. Thank you. As I'm using Finchley, I looked in its documentation. Has the handling changed or can I use the code also for Finchley?

Comment: Yeah that should work. You can use the `SpanCustomizer` bean to do that. You will, however, modify the span that is the parent of the RPC span created for rest temlpate. To modify that one you would have to use the SpanAdjuster and modify the span before reporting it to Zipkin I guess.

Comment: Please excuse me bothering you again. If I understood you correctly, I should use `SpanCustomizer` and set the Span's tag `peer.service` to the desired value. Could you please have a look at my implementation in the edited question and possibly tell if there is something wrong? Thank you very much.

Comment: If I understood you correctly (you want to modify the service name that you're calling via rest template) then you didn't understand me correctly. Just try out what you did and you'll see that the span related to the controller will be modified. And you wanted to change the service you're calling via `RestTemplate`. So you need to use the `SpanAdjuster` to find your particular span and add the annotation to it. Or if that's a service you don't want to continue the trace then you can do sth similar to the redis code but with `RestTemplate` create with `new` and not injected

Comment: Thanks Marcin, I guess you didn't understand me correctly: I don't want to edit a service's name but to add it to the dependency-graph: When I call 'httpbin' from 'serviceA', Zipkin's dependency graph just shows me that 'serviceA' took x seconds to complete the request. I would now be interested in seeing a graph that links 'httpbin' with 'serviceA' so I know that there is a dependency on 'httpbin' in that service. Is that possible? Sorry for my bad explaining skills :(

Comment: That should work out of the box once you provide the service name

Comment: Ok, unfortunately it isn't. But I managed to accomplish what I was looking for by adding these lines around my call: `Span span = tracer.newTrace().name("httpbinGet"); span.remoteEndpoint(Endpoint.newBuilder().serviceName("httpbin").build()); span.start(); call(); span.finish();`. Thank you anyway.

Comment: I've updated the answer to contain part for Edgware and part for Finchley